# Parsing 'json-like' text

Tags: r

I'm trying to parse a string in the below format:

```
[{'name': 'Mae Tech', 'id': 102}, {'name': "Walters' Company", 'id': 98}, 
  {'name': 'Brad & Bouy Inc.', 'id': 678}, {'name': 'Dowi Enterprises', 'id': 7678}, 
  {'name': 'Gamer Boys', 'id': 7678}, {'name': 'LogoMan', 'id': 3456}]
```

Here's the challenge I'm facing:

- I can't convert this to json because the field has single quotes and
  not double quotes.
- I can't gsub single quotes to double, because of apostrophes in the name.
- I can work on regex, but I'm not sure what all characters to include as my match condition. So far I've got: `'name': ('|\")[A-Za-z .'-]*"`

But I'm having to verify a lot of fields to ensure I'm not missing any.

Any simpler ideas?

Comment: You could use string splitting instead of regex matching - e.g. split at `},`, remove `[]{`, split at `,`, split at `:\\s`, remove `^[\\'\\"]` and `[\\'\\"]$`

Comment: @AndrewGustar.. I implemented something similar, thanks for the lead. I'd like to give credit to your suggestion. Let me know how I can do so.

Comment: Thanks - glad it was helpful.  I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use string splitting instead of regex matching - e.g. split at `},`, remove `[]{`, split at `,`, split at `:\\s`, remove `^[\\'\\"]` and `[\\'\\"]$` (or just remove the first and last character of string values, as these will be quotes of one sort or other).

Here is a `tidyverse` version, but there are other ways...

```
library(tidyverse) #uses dplyr and stringr

x <- "[{'name': 'Mae Tech', 'id': 102}, {'name': \"Walters' Company\", 'id': 98}, 
  {'name': 'Brad & Bouy Inc.', 'id': 678}, {'name': 'Dowi Enterprises', 'id': 7678}, 
  {'name': 'Gamer Boys', 'id': 7678}, {'name': 'LogoMan', 'id': 3456}]"

str_split(x, "\\},")[[1]] %>%                            #split at "},"
  str_remove_all("[\\[\\]\\{\\}]") %>%                   #remove assorted brackets "{}[]"
  str_split_fixed(", ", 2) %>%                           #split at ", "
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%            #convert to dataframe
  set_names(c("name", "id")) %>%                         #set column names
  mutate_all( ~ str_trim(str_remove(., ".+:\\s+"))) %>%  #remove bit up to ": " and trim
  mutate(name = substr(name, 2, nchar(name) - 1))        #remove end quotes from name

              name   id
1         Mae Tech  102
2 Walters' Company   98
3 Brad & Bouy Inc.  678
4 Dowi Enterprises 7678
5       Gamer Boys 7678
6          LogoMan 3456
```